# Getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' while loading react js web app from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-304

I am new in react,
I developed application and it is deployed on server but now getting errors as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

[image]

Also in bundle.js and other build js files loading shows 304 status code.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Did you merge any changes recently? Usually this occurs due to `<<<<< HEAD` being left in while merging changes

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing this error?

Comment: @LoXatoR, No I havent merged any code.

Comment: Please include the code that triggers this error

Comment: Looks like the server is returning index.html document on /static/js/*.js urls